# Missing a certain Haskell type conversion

Tags: haskell, casting

In GHCiOnline, `let listRestDiv 4 = floor(4/(fromInteger (nextPrimeDiv 4)))` does work, but the general

```
let listRestDiv n = floor(n/(fromInteger (nextPrimeDiv n)))
```

is not accepted, where `nextPrimeDiv n` is given by

```
let nextPrimeDiv n = head [x|x<-[1..n], n `mod` x == 0, x/=1]
```

and just returns the next prime divisor.

It says:

> Could not deduce (RealFrac Integer) arising from a use of `floor' from
>   the context (Integral b) bound by the inferred type of listRestDiv ::
>   Integral b => Integer -> b at

and ends there. I just dont get the types right here.
Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: it's good practice to add the type, and in this case it will solve the problem.

Comment: As @KarolyHorvath indicates, it is good practice to write type signatures for all top-level identifiers, and also for some non-top-level identifiers and expressions. Doing so lets you check in with the compiler to make sure the two of you agree on the type of what you've defined before moving on to other things. Although this particular problem is a fairly simple one, you will, one day, get some horrible type checker spew that makes no sense to you—adding as many type signatures as you can will help you figure out exactly where the error is. The `ScopedTypeVariables` will help a lot sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual complete error message received, hints us the fix to this problem.

```
Prelude> let listRestDiv n = floor(n/(fromInteger (nextPrimeDiv n)))

<interactive>:8:21:
    Could not deduce (RealFrac Integer) arising from a use of `floor'
    from the context (Integral b)
      bound by the inferred type of
               listRestDiv :: Integral b => Integer -> b
      at <interactive>:8:5-59
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Integer)
    In the expression: floor (n / (fromInteger (nextPrimeDiv n)))
    In an equation for `listRestDiv':
        listRestDiv n = floor (n / (fromInteger (nextPrimeDiv n)))

<interactive>:8:28:
    Could not deduce (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of `/'
    from the context (Integral b)
      bound by the inferred type of
               listRestDiv :: Integral b => Integer -> b
      at <interactive>:8:5-59
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Integer)
    In the first argument of `floor', namely
      `(n / (fromInteger (nextPrimeDiv n)))'
    In the expression: floor (n / (fromInteger (nextPrimeDiv n)))
    In an equation for `listRestDiv':
        listRestDiv n = floor (n / (fromInteger (nextPrimeDiv n)))
```

The important thing to be noted here is

```
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Integer)
    In the first argument of `floor', namely
      `(n / (fromInteger (nextPrimeDiv n)))'
```

So, all you have to do is, use `fromInteger` for `n` also, like this

```
Prelude> let listRestDiv n = floor(fromInteger n/(fromInteger (nextPrimeDiv n)))
```

Comment: unfortunately, it was cut just there

Comment: Note that ``floor(fromInteger n/fromInteger ...) = n `div` ...``

Comment: `\n -> n \`div\` nextPrimeDiv n` is also more efficient, and can be written as `div <$> id <*> nextPrimeDiv` if you are masochistic.

Comment: @Mr. F I agree and I reworded that sentence. Please check.